# C++ ScopeTryLock Macro

Tags: c++, c++11, synchronization, mutex

Hi have a mutex and would like to make a TryScopeLock which would be used like

```
if (ScopeTryLock(mutex))
{
   ...
}
```

The idea being that if the mutex can be locked it is and the if statement is entered. Otherwise its skipped.

Im trying to use this macro and class to achieve it

```
#define ScopeTryLock(lock) (_ScopeTryLock &lock = _ScopeTryLock::MakeTryLock(lock, __FILE__, __LINE__).tryToLock()).ownsLock()

class _ScopeTryLock
{
    bool didLock;
    const char *file;
    const int line;
public:
    static _ScopeTryLock MakeTryLock(Mutex& m, char* file, int line)
    {
        return _ScopeTryLock(m, file, line);
    }

    _ScopeTryLock(Mutex& m, char* file, int line) : mutex(m), didLock(false), file(file), line(line){}

    ~_ScopeTryLock() 
    {
        if (didLock) 
        {
            mutex.Unlock((char *) file, line);
        }
    }

    _ScopeTryLock &tryToLock()
    {
        if (mutex.TryLock((char *)file, line))
        {
            didLock = true;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool ownsLock() 
    {
        return didLock;
    }

protected:
    Mutex& mutex;
};
```

The issue is I cant figure out the proper macro to make this work the way i want. I tryed

```
#define ScopeTryLock(lock) _ScopeTryLock::MakeTryLock(lock, __FILE__, __LINE__).tryToLock().ownsLock()
```

but this didnt work as it seems to call the destructor when it enters the if statement which is not what i want. I also want to stay away from using the heap. Any ideas how to get this working?

edit:

sorry i should specify this is c++11. Also i dont have much flexibility with the mutex i am using. The mutex has a .Try() which will return true if the lock was successful and false if it wasn't. This is my only mechanism for interacting with the mutex (of course i can lock and unlock it). I would really like to figure out some c++ magic to make this work as i want in the if statment. Might be impossible i guess :(

Comment: Are you using a compiler that supports C++17?

Comment: Why not use standard threads? Using a `std::lock_guard` with the [std::try_to_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag) strategy, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++17, you can use a [new veriion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements) of the `if` statement where you can declare a variable for the duration of the code controlled by the if.

```
#define ScopeTryLock(mutex) ScopeTryLock lock(ScopeTryLock::MakeTryLock(lock, __FILE__, __LINE__)); lock.tryToLock().ownsLock()
```

(Note:  There are no parenthesis around this, and the semicolon separates the init statement from the condition.)  This will declare a variable `lock` that will remain in scope for the duration of the `if` statement (and `else` if there is one).

Then, when you use it in an if statement

```
if (ScopeTryLock(mutex))
```

it will create a variable (named `lock`) that will not be destryoed until the body of the `if` has finished executing.